# Lock row in postgres trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, locking, deadlock

In a postgres AFTER INSERT [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html) the called function (f) both reads and writes another row in the same table (tab).

```
my_trg AFTER INSERT ON tab FOR EACH ROW WHEN (some_condition) EXECUTE PROCEDURE f()
```

When under load, this leads to a deadlock.

> deadlock detected DETAIL: Process 27874 waits for ShareLock on transaction 316579928; blocked by process 27882. Process 27882 waits for ShareLock on transaction 316579930; blocked by process 27874.

My current understanding is that:

- two `INSERT` operations are started, each in a transaction
- the two inserts progress until the trigger function
- both triggers attempt to read and write to the same exact row

The trigger is a form of accounting, e.g. we increment an int (let's say `k = 0` at the beginning). The sequence of events may be:

```bash
TRIGGER-1 READ  tab.row.k # => k=0
TRIGGER-2 READ  tab.row.k # => k=0
TRIGGER-1 WRITE tab.row.k # => k=1
TRIGGER-2 attempts to WRITE tab.row.k but fails
```

Trigger-2 tries to apply a write based on a value that Trigger-1 have changed in meantime.

How to mitigate this effect, i.e. is it possible or sensible to lock the row in question within the trigger?

---

For reference, the simplified structure of the trigger.

```sql
-- performs TreeNode file accounting on INSERT
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.deleted THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    UPDATE data
    SET
        file_count = file_count + 1,
        size = COALESCE(size, 0) + COALESCE(NEW.size, 0)
    WHERE
        path @> (
            SELECT path
            FROM data
            WHERE id = NEW.parent_id
        );

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Try adding to your function a `set lock_timeout = '4s';` or N seconds after a trial and error tests to tune this time, to give this transaction more time to complete before it's rolled back because of deadlock.

Comment: You could also tune the queries involved in those transactions via explain analyze to find ways to optimize its execution time.